# Use of Spring controller with JSF

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine, jsf-2

I am using JSF primefaces with GAE/Java.When I moved to spring security framework, the controller has no effect in the application as jsf directly go to java backing bean. So can anyone suggest how can I use spring controller effectively with JSF to follow MVC architecture.Thanks in advance!

Any better security framework can I add instead of Spring?

Answer (score 0):

JSF *does* follow MVC architecture - badly, but it does it.

Why do you think you need Spring for web MVC?  I'd say you should either use JSF or Spring web MVC, but not both at the same time.  (I'd also recommend Spring over JSF.)

Spring has a security framework, but it's much more than that.

The question to ask is: what does "better" mean to you?  What problems are you having with Spring security?

If you're using it as soulcheck recommends below, then I'd say that you should wire in JSF and have a `DispatcherServlet` along side it to deal with file upload URLs.  Annotate Controllers only for non-JSF URLs and it should work.

Comment: there's one use case when he might want to use both: file downloads. Using Spring controllers instead of servlets is always tempting, especially in pre EE 6 environments.

Comment: I am happy to use Spring security, and no doubt it is highly recommended.The problem is I think JSF with Spring controller had poor effect(Or I don't know how to use it effectively). But I use the term "better" for the one that is highly compatible with JSF.

Comment: JSF has a "poor effect" even if you use it alone.  I'd ditch it.

Answer (score 0):

> *the controller has no effect in the application as jsf directly go to java backing bean*

You have to let it dispatch the request to `/j_spring_security_check`.

```
public void login() throws IOException {
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();
    externalContext.dispatch("/j_spring_security_check");
    facesContext.responseComplete();
}
```

#### See also

- [Acegi/Spring Security login page with JSF](http://ocpsoft.com/java/acegi-spring-security-jsf-login-page/)

Comment: In the case of login it will be fine. But how can I bring the JSF in to an MVC architecture?

Comment: This question makes no sense. Please elaborate.

Comment: Actually I had used Spring framework with JSP built on an MVC architecture. But now I moved to JSF. So the concept of spring controller make poor sense(or controller part is not needed). So I just want to know can I utilize the concept of MVC while using JSF if yes how?Hope you got my question!

Comment: JSF **is** a MVC framework. The "spring controller" part is to be done by a backing bean action method. The model can be made a property of the bean. See also http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/01/jsf-20-tutorial-with-eclipse-and.html for some concrete examples.